# How to order the most frequent data in a table

Tags: r

How to get the most frequent data in the column

data :

```
column 1 | column 2

"hi"     | "user1"

"text"   | "user1"

"text2"  | "user1"

"halo"   | "user2"

"hi"     | "user2"

"test"   | "user3"

"ok"     | "user1"
```

Expected Result :

```
Users Column | Count Column

"user1"      | "4"

"user2"      | "2"

"user1"      | "1"
```

Comment: `sort(table(your_data$name_of_user_column), decreasing = TRUE)`

Comment: thx bro it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution.

```
library(dplyr)
column_1=c("hi", "text", "text2", "halo", "hi", "test", "ok" )
column_2 =c("user1", "user1", "user1", "user2", "user2","user3", "user1")
df = data.frame(column_1, column_2)

group_by(df, column_2) %>%
  summarise(count=n()) %>%
  head()
```

Output:

```
column_2 count
  <fct>    <int>
1 user1        4
2 user2        2
3 user3        1
```